# Can't drop primary key from a table with CDC even if it's disabled

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in a database which is under change data capture:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo',
    @source_name   = N'mytable',
    @role_name     = NULL,
    @supports_net_changes = 1
```

I need to refactor this table for performance reasons, for which I need to drop the primary key; so I am doing:

```
 EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table 
      @source_schema = N'dbo', 
      @source_name   = 'mytable', 
      @capture_instance = N'dbo_mytable'
```

If I check if the table is tacked in `sys.tables.is_tracked_by_cdc` it shows 0.

```
 SELECT * FROM sys.tables tb 
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = tb.schema_id 
 WHERE s.name='dbo' and tb.name='mytable'
```

Nevertheless, when I drop the primary key doing `ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable drop constraint PK_mytable;` I get:

> The primary key constraint 'PK_mytable' on table 'mytable' cannot be dropped because change tracking is enabled on the table. Change tracking requires a primary key constraint on the table. Disable change tracking before dropping the constraint.

Why does the server believe the table is still under CDC even though it's disabled? Any idea how can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure you are dropping the constraint from the correct table (and correct server!)

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure

Comment: Double-check, because the Object Explorer and query window can have differing connections. Maybe the capture instance name is wrong, try `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name   = 'mytable', @capture_instance = N'all'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You disabled `change data capture`, but the error is relating to `change tracking`. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable]
DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING;
```